# springfox-swagger-ui: How to exclude routes from global parameter

Tags: java, swagger-ui

Say I created a global parameter `token` for all my APIs:

```
    List<Parameter> commonParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    commonParameters.add(new ParameterBuilder()
        .name("token")
        .description("Token for api access")
        .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
        .parameterType("header")
        .required(true)
        .build());
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .globalOperationParameters(commonParameters)
       // rest ignored .....
```

This token is required for almost every API, except one that can be publicly accessed. How do I exclude this one API from the global operation parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently exclusion for `globalOperationParameters` is not provided and there's an open feature request for the same in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1910).

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found is to override globally defined header by using `@ApiImplicitParams` annotation.

So in your case:

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
        //Overriding global behavior.
        @ApiImplicitParam(
                name = "token")
})
```

Unfortunately, header will be still visible on swagger, but parameter won't be marked as required.